# Replace html of a td

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can we replace first  html in jquery.I want to replace the input type whose id is code.with a drop down on click of a check box .

**HTML**

```
<tr class="inputstr">
        <td style="font-size:12px">Code</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="code" name="code" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px">Charges1 </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="charges_id1" name="charges_id2" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px">Charges2 </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="charges_id2" name="charges_id2" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px">Charges3 </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="charges_id3" name="charges_id3" value=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The input type whose id is code i want to replace that with a drop down that.How can we do this in jquery.Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**:

> Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided
>   new content and return the set of elements that was removed.

```
$('#code').replaceWith('<select><option>1</option></select>');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xBVDq/)**

Answer (score 0):

Based on checkbox click this will change the content use `replaceWith`

Try this

```
$('#chg').on('click',function(){
    $('#code').replaceWith('<select><option>1</option></select>');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x27ub/)

Answer (score -1):

For the td of charges_id1 for example:

```
$('#charges_id1').parent().html('<Your html here>');
```